# Cronjob vs User compiled script

Tags: php, cron

I was thinking of programming a game in which battles are fight between players. I have done some research and read about two different ways of performing tasks when the player who's army is fighting is not online.

1. use a cronjob to, lets say, every 5 minutes start a script to go
   through a wait list of tasks.
2. make every user, when log in in or requesting any page start
   that same script.

Now my question is. What is the advantage/disadvantage of the first solution.
And when I use the second solution, I will end up doing something like:

1. Fetching the not jet performed tasks from the database by comparing "now" with a "last modified" date
2. Change the "last modified" date to "now"
3. Perform tasks

But do I not run the risk that a second user is opening the script in between step 1 and 2 and therefore performing the tasks twice?

Looking forward to your opinion.

Comment: Hi Martin, firstly this question is probably going to be closed as "primarily opinion based" - but in spite of that I'll provide mine: you should use a cron job for anything that is either long running or not essential to be run immediately (i.e. awarding things). You shouldn't lay too much onto the user, but leave them to process tasks that relate directly to their account. This way you shouldn't have conflicts with others using your system. If you define a cron job, you'd probably want to run it every minute to ensure that things are updated quickly.

Comment: If you run cron to fetch some data from database and then update the database - you don't need to do that. MySQL has something called Event Scheduler. You use it to run queries at predefined time intervals and the database can maintain itself, update tables etc.

Comment: Let’s consider what @Mjh suggested option 3. Option 4 would be to _not_ run stuff regularly in the first place, but simply apply math (if applicable in your context.) If you have f.e. an action that increases the value of X every Y minutes – then you don’t necessarily need to _run_ something every Y minutes to update that value, but instead when some user access that data, you simply _calculate_ the current value there and then.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what is meant by option 3? Is this something different than using a cron job? If I consider option 4, that is basically similar to option 2 except for the fact that a user does only access and process the data he needs. For my case that would not work as the data of user A and B might influence the game for player C.